Encrypting and Decrypting same PDF file android java
I am trying to implement encryption and decryption on a PDF file. Usually encryption and decryption is done by encrypting a file and storing it as a new encrypted file and vice versa for decryption. But I want to implement encryption on the same file and storing the path in ROOM.
Lock/Encryption
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File file = new File(Consts.MERGE_FETCH_LOC, "LockedPDF");
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.mkdir();
                }
                if (doc != null) {
                    String src = doc.getDocPath();
                    String pass = editText.getText().toString();
                    try {
                        String res = lock(src, pass);
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                documentDAO.insert(doc);
                            }
                        }).start();
                        fileSaver.deleteTempImage(res);
                        Toast.makeText(LockPDFActivity.this, "PDF Locked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(LockPDFActivity.this, MainFeaturesActivity.class));
                        finishAffinity();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(LockPDFActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private String lock(String src, String pass) throws IOException {

        //make a copy of current file
        File currentFile = new File(src);
        File temp = new File(getFilesDir(),currentFile.getName());
        PDFFileUtils.copyFile(this,currentFile, temp);
        try (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(temp);
             FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(src))) {

            WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
            writerProperties.setStandardEncryption(pass.getBytes(), pass.getBytes(), EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING, EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);

            PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(outputStream, writerProperties);

            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, pdfWriter);

            pdfDoc.close();

            return temp.getAbsolutePath();
        }
    }


Unlock/Decryption
private String unLock(String src, String pass) {
        // Make a copy of the current file
        File currentFile = new File(src);
        Log.d("de_unlock", "unLock: "+currentFile.getName());
        File temp = new File(getFilesDir(), currentFile.getName());
        PDFFileUtils.copyFile(this, currentFile, temp);

        // Try to unlock the PDF file
        try (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src, new ReaderProperties().setPassword(pass.getBytes()));
             PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(temp.getAbsolutePath())) {
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
            pdfDocument.close();

            return src;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("UnlockPDFActivity", "Error unlocking PDF: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }

I want to encrypt and decrypt the same file. File is being encrypted successfully but when I try to decrypt it, the app crashes with the error of PDF Header not found. Please guide me where I am doing it wrong.
